# Using a conditional inside a foreach loop when adding to array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm scraping a website using a xpath selector and this returns 38 results which are added to the array $list. Now the first 5 results and the last 3 are useless to me. What I need is to only add results 6-35 to the array. I've tried many different combinations of if, for and while conditionals but can't seem to get this to work. I'd love to hear what I'm doing wrong and finally get this to work.

```
$url = "www.theurl.com";
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);

$nodelist = $xpath->query("//span[@class='mp-listing-title']");

$list = array();

$i = 0;

foreach ($nodelist as $n) {
  $i++;
}
if ($i >=5 && $i <=35) {
  $value = $n->nodeValue;
  $list[] = $value;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are closing foreach loop too early leaving the if condition out of the loop or is that a typo....?

Comment: You should put that as the answer @SudhirBastakoti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it can help you:

```
 $url = "www.theurl.com";
 $html = new DOMDocument();
 @$html->loadHtmlFile($url);
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);

 $nodelist = $xpath->query("//span[@class='mp-listing-title']");

 $list = array();

 $i = 0;

 foreach ($nodelist as $n) {
   if ($i >=5 && $i <=35) {
     $value = $n->nodeValue;
     $list[] = $value;
   }
   $i++;
 }
```

Comment: Since nodelist is obviously a list array, wouldn't it be more correct to use `for($i=0; $i<count($nodelist); $i++)` and then access `$nodelist[$i]->nodeValue` instead of foreach and then manually increment `$i`?

Comment: Here is a better desciprition of your question [PHP for() VS foreach()](https://coderwall.com/p/il1tog/php-for-vs-foreach-benchmark)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$url = "www.theurl.com";
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);

$nodelist = $xpath->query("//span[@class='mp-listing-title']");

$list = array();

$i = 0;

foreach ($nodelist as $n)  {
  if ($i >=5 && $i <=35) {
    $value = $n->nodeValue;
    $list[] = $value;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Your conditional was out side of the loop.